# Fully clone React component, including input values

Tags: reactjs

I'm just wondering if there's anyway of completely cloning an already rendered `React` component. I've read about `cloneElement` but when I render that clone I get an error:

> Uncaught error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid

I'm also wondering if this will clone the element's child elements, and their subsequent input values. For example, if some text is in one of the inputs, and then the component is cloned, will these values be preserved? Or is my only option to store those values before clone? This will make it very tightly coupled I feel.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, we should always try to keep our components as stateless as possible, meaning that the data you input in the form should be stored somewhere outside of the component (a Store, maybe? ... I'm thinking about http://alt.js.org/docs/stores/).

With this approach, you'll have your component listening to that store. You can have as many copies of the component as you'd like, but the single source of truth would be your store.

Another scenario, if the same component should show data from different stores, then do not use stores, and use props. Have the parent component be the one listening to its store, and pass the necessary data to the child component (the one that you want to have clones in several places in your app).

I hope that helps,